# Animate two uiview together

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

Assuming the height of main view as h.

I have two uivivew both height h/2(let us call them up and down view).

I want to add up and down swipe gesture such that

-If I swipe up

1. If down view and up view height is h/2 and I swipe up then the down view height must be made h and up view height must be made 0.
2. If up view height is h and down view height is 0 the down view and up view height must be made h/2

I want to animate things so that the height increase and decrease must be visible smoothly.

Comment: do you want the animation transition smooth? or rather on going continuous or track as your movements? or just a little push up will start the animation?

Comment: What did you try? Please post your code also.

Comment: create the two seperate timeinterval for this animation

Answer (score 1):

1. set vertical constraints for both Up and Down in Main view so that their vertical spacing is 0, top of Up to Main is 0, and bottom of Down to Main is also 0.
2. set a height constraint for Down view, constant 0, multiplier 1. Hook this constraint to an IBOutlet.
3. When you swipe, check if that constraint constant is 0, then set to h/2, if h/2 then set to h. After that, tell the view to layoutIfNeeded to update with the new constraint parameters. You can add animation for layout if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   [self initialization];
 }

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   [self viewDesign];
 }

-(void)initialization{
   viewUpHeight.constant=self.view.frame.size.height/2;
   viewDownHeight.constant=self.view.frame.size.height/2;
 }

-(void)viewDesign{
     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUpGestureRecognizer =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUp:)];
     swipeUpGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
     [self.view  addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpGestureRecognizer];

      UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDownGestureRecognizer =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDown:)];
      swipeDownGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
      [self.view  addGestureRecognizer:swipeDownGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void)swipeUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGes{
   if(viewUp.frame.size.height==self.view.frame.size.height) {

    }else {
    CGRect basketTopFrame = self.viewUp.frame;
    basketTopFrame.origin.y = -basketTopFrame.size.height;
    // basketTopFrame.size.height=0;

    CGRect basketBottomFrame = self.viewDown.frame;
    basketBottomFrame.size.height=self.view.frame.size.height;
    basketBottomFrame.origin.y =0;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    self.viewUp.frame = basketTopFrame;
    self.viewDown.frame = basketBottomFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
}

-(void)swipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGes{

   if(viewDown.frame.size.height==self.view.frame.size.height){
   CGRect basketTopFrame = self.viewUp.frame;

   basketTopFrame.origin.y =0;

   CGRect basketBottomFrame = self.viewDown.frame;
   basketBottomFrame.origin.y =self.view.frame.size.height/2;
   basketBottomFrame.size.height=self.view.frame.size.height/2;

   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
   [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
   [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

   self.viewUp.frame = basketTopFrame;
   self.viewDown.frame = basketBottomFrame;

   [UIView commitAnimations];
  }
}
```